# Excel Data Validation Get Unique Values of Record from a Named Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel Table named Table5 which consist of two columns CompanyCode and EmployeeLevel. Now my question is i want to get the unique values of EmployeeLevel columns. Take note that the length of the record is unknown. I am using the Table5[EmployeeLevel] as the range to include all the records in the Table5. Is there a formula that you can provide ? I cannot use ActiveX object to loop through each record. I must do it via Excel formula. The solutions I got are only usable when it is fixed how long the records are. but this record I am working on is a dynamic table.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data looks like this:

[image: Table5]

The easiest way to do this is to create a Pivot Table based on Table5. In the Rows, add EmployeeLevel. In Data, add EmployeeLevel.

[image]

Change the data aggregation to `Count` rather than sum. You will get something like this.

[image]

When you add a new item to Table5, all you need to do is update the PivotTable (right-click on the PivotTable and click update).

If you need to use formulas, the following is a workaround.

In Column C, add the following formula (given the below data, adjust to fit):

```
=--(COUNTIF($B$1:$B2,$B2)=1)
```

This will return a `1` for every unique value in the table.

Somewhere on the sheet (in my case F2), I added the following formula to count unique values:

```
=SUM(Table5[Unique Value])
```

In my sample data, there are 14.

I then copied the following formula from F3 down 20 rows (I used 20 because I don't have that many unique values -- you say your table is variable, so pick a number of rows higher than the amount of unique values you expect in the future):

```
{=IF(ROW(A1)<=F$2,SMALL(IF(Table5[Unique Value]=1,Table5[EmployeeLevel]),ROW(A1)),"")}
```

<sub>Note -- the curly braces are an array formula -- do not add them by hand, enter the formula without them and confirm with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd></sub>

This will result in the unique values in ascending order:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve the count from within the table itself, provided `EmployeeLevel` is sorted:

[image: SO18393935 example]